# operator | for int value

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I think this is a basic in java,  but sorry, I ask in stackoverflow.

I will give an example in eclipse RCP.  For example, if I want to make instance of Text (swt text), I would do below:

```
Text text = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI);
```

In second parameter Text, it is a int style, and I would the text will be border and can be multi line, so I add SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI (the operator | will be used).

Now the question, for example I add already have a variable int style by the method getStyle() in the Text class.  But I want to check if the SWT.MULTI is already set or not, how can I archive it?  Thanks

Comment: Stupid question never exists :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool multiIsSet = (x & SWT.MULTI) == SWT.Multi
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is the bitwise & operator.

```
if (myText.getStyle() & SWT.MULTI){
 //whatever
}
```

Comment: Also, it won't damage anything if you add SWT.MULTI to something that is styled with SWT.MULTI already. Take a look at this article, and read up on how SWT uses bitwise operators: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: You need a `!= 0` in there. `if`s in Java require a boolean expression.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I already check before with code above, but the result is 2 (same with SWT.MULTI) when I use SWT.MULTI, and 0 when not using SWT.MULTI.  It is correct

Comment: Sorry, yes for clarity of code if nothing else I would put a != 0 in there.